# How to check which programmes are scheduled to run in windows?

Tags: windows, cron

Like `crontab` in linux,is there a solution?

I mean,it's run at a specific time,for instance,12 o'click every day.

So it's not `services.msc`

Comment: Did you mean "which programs are routinely run?" or
"which programs have been scheduled to run?".

Please clarify.

Comment: I know there are lots of helpful answers, but this should really be a Serverfault question.

Comment: Oh,it should be **scheduled** to run.

Answer (score 4):

You'd want to check the Windows Scheduler, Control Panel -> Scheduled Tasks.

[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) is a useful program that shows all sorts of stuff that runs on a windows box.

Answer (score 3):

It's called the [Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

For scheduled execution of applications or jobs, you can use the [task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler)

You can also use [windows services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service) in order to schedule long running jobs or see what services are running.

On XP, you can go to start->run and run 'services.msc' to see this list.

Answer (score 0):

The answer involves a few different tools in windows:

1. To view the current running applications and processes you can use Task Manager or better yet the sysinternals suite of tools - in particular Process Monitor - that can be downloaded from microsoft, which provide even more info of the running processes. To get to task manager you can just do a CTRL+ALT+DELETE or right click on the windows toolbar and select Task Manager.
2. For something like crontab, there is Task Scheduler that you can use to schedule the running of scripts, applications, etc.
3. In windows you can also have applications running as services - similar to daemons. Under the administrative Tools in Contorl Panel you will see Services. If you double click it you will get a dialog that shows you all the services currently running. You can also create your own programs that run as services.

Answer (score 0):

its called the task scheduler, also, you can use the at command to set scheduling of task programmatically. See [here](http://www.computerhope.com/at.htm) for syntax

Answer (score 0):

Up through 2K:  [`at.exe`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313289)

On XP and beyond: [`schtasks.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Run Windows Task Manager;
right click the Task Bar
or key Ctrl+Alt+Delete
to launch Task Manager.

You can also run tasklist from
the command line. Type

```
tasklist /?
```

for usage.

Comment: you can also run msconfig to launch the System Configuration Utility.

It will show you things like which programs are set to launch on startup and it will also let you disable/enable selected programs.